# Laravel - Dynamic buttons using AJAX and JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

Hello I want to create a dynamic buttons I am not familiar in ajax or jquery though so please guide me, I already have this dynamic button running, but what I want is to create another dynamic button after I Add another form. so here is my code. See my Image, I cannot add another file button after I add form

Here is an image to show what I want and my problem is [image: Dynamic Button]

> What I have here is the Design of the Form

```
 <html>  
      <head>    
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  

                <div class="form-group">  
                     <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                    <tr>  
                                        <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">  

                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="areaName[]" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>

                                        <input type="file" name="fileName[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"><br>

  <!--I Want to add another File Button after clicking this button--> <button type="button" name="addFile" id="addFile" class="btn btn-success">Add Another Form</button>

                                        </td>  

                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  

                                    </tr>  
                               </table>  
                               <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

> Here is the AJAX Code which helps the program to run without refreshing and adding form like a loop

```
    <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td> <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">  <textarea class="form-control" name="areaName[]" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea><input type="file" name="fileName[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"><button type="button" name="addFile" id="addFile" class="btn btn-success">Add Another Form</button></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>

  <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#addFile').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="file" name="fileName[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"></button></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });   
 });  
 </script>
```

Comment: I have modified and improved your code please see my answer.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal Works fine except when I add form again the previous Add Another Form button is executing the second button can you please help me more on that thank you tho.. it is almost closed. I'll marked this as an answer once it has finished thank you sir

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal I would just like that every "Add Another Form" Button has its own dependencies. In short, they just add on their own arrays not on another arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trigger your event using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). See below-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
    var len = $('.form-row').length;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr class="form-row" data-id="'+len+'"><td> <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">  <textarea class="form-control" name="areaName[]" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea><input type="file" name="fileName[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"><button type="button" name="addFile" id="addFile" class="btn btn-success addFile">Add Another Form</button></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove_all">X</button></td></tr>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#add_name')[0].reset();
      }
    });
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.addFile', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.form-row').data('id');
    var elem = '<tr class="'+id+'"><td><input type="file" name="fileName[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"></button></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>';
    $(elem).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove, .btn_remove_all', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('btn_remove_all')){
      var id = $(this).closest('.form-row').data('id');
      $('tr.'+id).remove();
    }
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
      <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
            <tr class="form-row">
              <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">

                <textarea class="form-control" name="areaName[]" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>

                <input type="file" name="fileName[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"><br>

                <!--I Want to add another File Button after clicking this button--><button type="button" name="addFile" id="addFile" class="btn btn-success addFile">Add Another Form</button>

              </td>

              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success add">Add More</button></td>

            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, don't use `id` for trigger event on elements because its unique so if element will be repeated then event will not fire on other element.

Comment: Hello @Shubham Branwal I've tested your code. works fine but that first button array does not work it does work on the second button. it is close tho. can you please help me more thank you

Comment: Works fine except when I add form again the previous Add Another Form button is executing the second button can you please help me more on that thank you tho.. it is almost closed. I'll marked this as an answer once it has finished thank you sir

Comment: THANKS! You've saved me time this is the right answer

Comment: Oh sorry 'bout that ':) Im also new to Stackoverflow :).. see im just new in coding .. but people like you helped me and your logic is also good

Comment: Can you explain to me why it is not dependent on behalf of my logic sir? Why the arrays are just in the first button

Comment: You have always try to append element in the last when you add a new `input of type file` but it will be always insert as a sibling of your `tr` element.

Comment: Don't try to code too much. I think there is everything in jquery that makes your code simpler.

Comment: Sir, @Shubham , there's one more problem :( ... when I deleted the main form of arrays.. the SUB Contents are still showing they are not delete why is that sir

Comment: @Subham Baranwal , The Sub Content Arrays of the "Add Form File" Button are not deleted they are still they even after I delete the Main Array, please help sir for the last time thank you

Comment: delete element just deletes the row in which it belongs if you want to delete its sibling row then you have to select that.

Comment: Can you edit the code sir I am not really familiar with ajax code :( please help me Im close to this deadline.. :(

Comment: Ill wait for your reply sir, that is the last problem of the code. thank you very much in advanced

Comment: If I deleted the whole row, There are still sibling file buttons left

Comment: Thank you please let me know I will upvote all your answers thank you so much my project is now comlplete ill try to understand ajax syntax asap

Comment: Happy to helping you. If you find my answer helpful for you then up vote, no need of up voting all of my answers :). @SummerWinter

Comment: Don't you mind if you'll answer some of my questions again?

Comment: Yeah sure keep asking here anybody will answer your questions.